# Return keyboard focus

Tags: wpf, keyboard, focus

I have an application where the main window contains a user control, and inside that user control are items stored in an ItemsControl. Each item can be removed by clicking an 'x' button.

The problem I am facing is that although the Keyboard focus is initially set to the user control, when you remove an item, focus is then transferred to the main window, instead of *back* to the user control?

Is there a way I can fix this without having to add code behind to manually store/retrieve/set focus after the click?

I have lots of these buttons within my application and I'm trying to avoid having to add code all over the place to manage returning the Focus.

I have created a very simple example to show the issue :

```
    <UserControl x:Class="WpfApp28.MyControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid Width="300">
        <StackPanel>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                            <Button Content="x"
                                    Width="20"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                    Click="Button_Click" />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>



public partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
    public MyControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Focusable = true;
        Loaded += MyControl_Loaded;
    }

    private void MyControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Keyboard.Focus(this);
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is FrameworkElement fe && fe.DataContext is string item)
        {
            (DataContext as ObservableCollection<string>).Remove(item);
        }
    }
}

<Window x:Class="WpfApp28.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp28"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<local:MyControl DataContext="{Binding Items}" />
```

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> Items { get; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        Items.Add("hello");
        Items.Add("there");
        Items.Add("world");

        DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();

        DispatcherTimer t = new DispatcherTimer();
        t.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250);
        t.Tick += T_Tick;
        t.Start();
    }

    private void T_Tick(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Title = Keyboard.FocusedElement?.GetType().ToString() ?? "NULL";
    }
}
```

Comment: There are no good and clean options that I know of. The cleanest solution is to use FocusManger.SetFocus() in the code behind.

Comment: I was hoping that would not be the case. The problem is that in my application, the buttons are bound to commands on the view model, which doesn't know about the controls

Comment: May you can try to use the FocusManager as a property in your XAML. Something like that: FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"

Comment: I have found that can work for setting the initial focus, but not returning to the previous focus when an element is unloaded

Comment: Could you navigate to the next control before removing one? You'd want a preview leftmousedown or some such handled at itemscontrol level so it handled all the buttons in one place.

Comment: Yes, I think I can add handlers and what not, but I don't understand why it's happening in the first place? shouldn't it set the closest Ancestor? which would be the UserControl? .. why is it skipping it and going to the next Ancestor above that (the window)?

Comment: I think I'd have to see the real code and play round with it.
You could alternatively put a viewless control in the itemtemplate.  Bind a property to the item viewmodel. Call setfocus on it's parent.  So you could set a property in an item viewmodel and use that to drive setting focus to the ui for that item viewmodel.

Comment: BTW by "add handlers" I'm talking ONE handler. Handling a tunneling event from the children of that itemscontrol.

Comment: var request = new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next);
      request.Wrapped = true;
      AssociatedObject.MoveFocus(request);

Comment: But how do you know that the focus should change? what if the item has another button that doesn't remove but does something else (increase a value say). Now the preview event handling does the wrong thing.

Comment: You put a tag on the removal button and check it's there in the handler which'll have a reference to the button clicked. Or. You only set the property bound to your ui control in the command removes the item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that the keyboard focus moves to the hosting `Window` is obvious once you understand how WPF handles focus. It's important to know that WPF uses scopes in which the focus traverses the elements.
There can be multiple focus scopes allowing multiple elements to remain focused simultaneously.
By default, the hosting `Window` defines a focus scope. Since it is the only focus scope, it is global (the scope of the complete visual tree).

What happens in your code in short:

1. The Button receives the focus via mouse click
2. The click handler removes the clicked item and therefore the clicked Button from the visual tree
3. WPF moves focus back to the focus scope root, which is the `MainWindow` in your case

You have multiple options to prevent the focus from being moved back to the focus root. Some involve code-behind.

The following examples show how to move the focus back to the parent `UserControl`. But it could be any element as well:

1. You can configure the `Button` (the element that "steals" the current focus) to be not focusable. This only works if the `UserControl` is already focused:

```xml
<DataTemplate>
  <Button Content="x"
          Focusable="False" />
</DataTemplate>
```

2. You can introduce a new focus scope. Since you want the `UserControl` itself to be focused, you must choose the root element of the `UserControl`. You can achieve this by using the `FocusManager` helper class:

```xml
<UserControl>
  <Grid x:Name="RootPanel" 
        FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True"
        Width="300">
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

3. You can of course register a `Button.Click` handler or preferably a routed command to move the focus back to the `UserControl` explicitly. A routed command can be more convenient in most cases. It allows to send a command parameter that makes the code-behind simpler.
   Note, since `Button.Click` is a routed event, you can simply register  a `Button.Click` event handler on the `UserControl`. This example uses the existing click handler that is used to remove the item from the `ItemsControl`:

**UserControl.xaml**

```xml
<DataTemplate>
  <Button Content="x"
          Click="OnButtonClick" />
</DataTemplate>
```

**UserControl.xaml.cs**

```cs
private void OnButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs)
{
  /* Delete the item */

  Keyboard.Focus(this);
}
```

---

### Final suggested solution

To improve your code and handling of the `UserControl` you must definitely implement an `ItemsSource` dependency property and use a routed command to delete the items.

The following example uses the predefined `ApplicationCommands.Delete` routed command. You will notice how simple the code has become:

**MyControl.xaml.cs**

```cs
public partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
  public IList ItemsSource
  {
    get => (IList)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty);
    set => SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value);
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "ItemsSource",
    typeof(IList),
    typeof(UserControl4), new PropertyMetadata(default));

  public MyControl()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Focusable = true;
  }

  public override void OnApplyTemplate() 
    => Keyboard.Focus(this);


  private void DeleteItemCommand_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    => this.ItemsSource.Remove(e.Parameter);

  private void DeleteItemCommand_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    => e.CanExecute = this.ItemsSource.Contains(e.Parameter);
}
```

**MyControl.xaml**

```xml
<UserControl>
  <UserControl.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static ApplicationCommands.Delete}"
                    Executed="DeleteItemCommand_Executed"
                    CanExecute="DeleteItemCommand_CanExecute" />
  </UserControl.CommandBindings>

  <Grid x:Name="RootPanel" 
        FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True">
    <StackPanel>
      <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:UserControl4}, Path=ItemsSource}"
               >
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
              <Button Content="x"
                      Command="{x:Static ApplicationCommands.Delete}"
                      CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                      Width="20"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                      VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </Grid>
          </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window>
  <MyControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" />
</Window>
```

Remarks
You should consider to use a `ListBox` instead of the pure `ItemsControl`.
`ListBox` is an extended `ItemsControl`. It will significantly improve performance and provides a `ScrollViewer` by default.

Comment: Thank you, adding the FocusScope solved the problem. This is exactly the solution I was looking for and doesn't involve extra codebehind or manual focus handling. In regards to the code in my example. it was written like that intentionally to keep it small and to the point, as we're always advised that code examples should only contain what is needed to demonstrate the issue.